# Website administration tool to manage multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, wsat

I have an admin section in my webapp to manage users and roles (like the website administration tool). My question is : which is the best way to manage users and role for all sites running on a remote server ?
The idea is to have a single webapp administration tool on the remote server for all sites without replicate the admin section on each application.

Some of you has faced the same problem?

Comment: If your application is yours, then you must all ready know how to do that, if not, what application are you use and you need a global manager for your site ? In general I will say that you can do that only if you can control the server and give "common permissions" to your database or files that keep this users and roles